# CURL: have to specify cacert

Tags: curl, debian, ssl-certificate

I've got problem with curl and https. I have to specify `cacert` at every request, can somebody tell me what to do? I use debian jessie.

```
$ curl -XGET --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt 'https://www.google.com'
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=M69TWfebI4P_8AeJ1KPACA">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

when I don't specify the `cacert`:

```
$ curl -XGET 'https://www.google.com' -v
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 216.58.204.132...
* Connected to www.google.com (216.58.204.132) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS Unknown, Unknown (22):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv2, Unknown (22):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv2, Unknown (22):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv2, Unknown (21):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv2, Unknown (21):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Of course I don't want to ignore certification, I'd like to solve the issue.

My curl version:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2k zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Comment: can you add more details like the version of CURL and what is the current cacert path set to?

Comment: @KaushalKumarPanday here you go sorry for the delay. cacert path is shown in curl -v

Comment: I decided to uninstall and reinstall the package `ca-certificates`, and it solved the issue.

Comment: `# rm /etc/ca-certificates.conf`

`# apt-get clean`

`# apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`

Answer (score 1):

From the -v output looks like it is getting to the correct folder but unable to get a cert

> ```
> * successfully set certificate verify locations:
> *   CAfile: none
>   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> ```

Try doing this to update the current CA list.

```
cd /etc/ssl/certs
sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

I think curl looks into the .pem file and not the .crt file.  Also see this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/151157/ubuntu-10-04-curl-how-do-i-fix-update-the-ca-bundle

Comment: I had the same error after trying this. I decided to uninstall and reinstall the package ca-certificates, and now it works! Thanks a lot for your help :)